# Задание связи между таблицами sql server

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Задача построить ОШС организации с возможностью отслеживать начальников структурных   подразделений организации и начальников каждого сотрудника.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопросы по схеме:**

1) корректно ли указывать двойную связь "Сотрудник" относиться к "Структурному подразделению" и также "Структурное подразделение" имеет "Начальника (тип Сотрудник)"?

2) Есть ли предложения или советы по организации болеее корректной структуры?

3) Использование корпоративной почты как уникального идентификатора сотрудника хорошая практика или лучше искусственный идентификатор (счетчик записи)?

4) Правильнее ли строить в этом случае иерархию, или стоить рассмотреть реляционный подход?

**Дополнительная информация:**

Программа разрабатывается с учетом возможности разграничения доступа к планам на работы сотрудника для всех его начальников. Разработка ведется на  С#/EntityFramework.

Comment: 5) хорошо ли таким образом именовать поля 6) не странно ли, что все поля таблиц имеют текстовый тип

Comment: Структура в общем то корректная по связям. Но есть один нюанс, вы не сможете добавить подразделение не указав начальника и не сможете завести этого самого начальника, не указав подразделение. Решите кого первого вы будете заводить. Я бы остановился на подразделении, тогда необходимо разрешить NULL в начальнике подразделения.

Comment: @teran раскройте, пожалуйста, вопрос 5 и 6, не совсем ясно, к чему именно могут относиться замечания по наименованию и по шестому отвечу, что большая часть данных и правда имеет текстовый формат (см. вопрос 3)

Comment: Текстовые id это обычно плохо. Как вы будете давать id подразделениям ? А  почта как идентификатор ужастная идея. У нас недавно после слияния компаний у всех сотрудников изменили корпоративные почтовые адреса. А смена id и всех связей нетривиальная задача, особенно в случае циклической связи как у вас

Comment: лучше все id делать числовыми и оторванными от жизни (автогенерируемыми), кроме некоторых особых случаев.

Comment: @Mike аналогичная мысль пришла и мне в голову, в этом случае я бы использовала идентификатор (счетчик) записи.

Comment: У sql-server это называется IDENTITY и поле создается прямо с таким типом. А ссылающееся на него поле обычный int

Comment: @Mike по Id подразделений был выбран подход расширения ключа, путем добавления наименования текущего узла, например: depart (корневой узел), его отделы будут наименоваться depart.otdel1 и depart.otdel2 и далее по иерархии.

Comment: А что вы будете делать при изменении иерархии, какой нибудь отдел перевели в другой департамент ? ну или просто при вводе ошиблись и хотят перенести... Это надо не только поменять id текущего узла, но и всех, которые на него ссылаются, рекурсивно. А потом обновить информацию у сотрудников и все это выполнить так, что бы ни в какой момент времени не произошло нарушения ключей

Comment: @Mike я правильно понимаю что эта проблема возникаем именно из-за  подхода выбора текстового ключа, и получается и здесь стоит применять  счетчик как первичный ключ?

Comment: Проблема возникает в любом случае если ключ зависит от каких либо других атрибутов записи. Или зависит от чего то, что может изменится во внешнем мире. Идея в том, что за время жизни записи ключ не должен изменятся никогда. Если у вас будет таблица Российских юрлиц, то вы вполне можете сделать ключем ОГРН, он вроде как никогда не меняется, но ИНН делать первичным ключом явно не стоит, он хоть и уникален, но может изменится за время жизни организации. По этой причине автоинкрементный автоматически генерируемый id почти всегда лучше